# C : Unable to open file in modeFatal

Tags: file-io

I compiled a C code using make then afterwards I issued this command on linux terminal

./regex --parse /ruleset/snort34.re --debug

where snort34.re is a file which I want to open for parsing but it gives me this error

Unable to open file in /ruleset/snort.re in modeFatal

Can anyone please help me why I am getting this error and what is modeFatal?

Comment: `modeFatal` is two words, possibly due to a bad `printf` statement.

Comment: In order to answer the question, we need to know **what** code you're trying to run!

Comment: ...does it work if you write `--parse ruleset/snort34.re`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passed `/ruleset/snort34.re` to the program, which will look in a folder in your *root* directory called `ruleset`. You probably want to use a relative path instead, `ruleset/snort34.re`.